# iFrame scrolling not working on iOS devices

Tags: ios, css, iframe

I have responsive site which have an `issue of scrolling` because of iFrame.

```
# Problem

> Open site in iPhone in any browser
> list of images and video display
> Try to scroll down then it's work while images but when video then scrolling not worked because of video display in iFrame and iOS device not allow to scroll on `iFrame`.
```

Is there any CSS trick or any particular issue with iOS devices?

It's `not work in iPhone / iPad.`

```
NOTE: I do not want to scroll into iFrame but page scroll not working when touch on iFrame and try to page down. Got it?
```

Let me know if any one sort this issue or any trick.

Thanks

Comment: did U fix this issue? I met with the same issue. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Try,

```
.iframe-container {
    overflow:scroll !important; -webkit-overflow-scrolling:touch !important;
}
```

Comment: iframe-container class not created. Should add?

Comment: add your class.

Comment: This class should be add to parent div of iFrame? Right ? Like...
<div class="iframe-container">
<iFrame ...> </iFrame>
</div>

Comment: I do not want to scroll into iFrame but page scroll not working when touch on iFrame and try to page down. Got it?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to the iframe container:

```
-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
```

Comment: I do not want to scroll into iFrame but page scroll not working when touch on iFrame and try to page down. Got it?