# Unable to scroll iFrame on mobile device

Tags: html, iframe, scroll

Scroll is not working on my iframe when I access my website from mobile device browser. It works perfectly fine on my laptop.

Here is my html:

```
<div style="align: center; position:relative;">
<div class="modal-header" style="background-color: transparent;position:absolute;top:0;right: 0;border: 0px;">
    <button type="button" class="close" ng-click="cancel()">
        <span aria-hidden="true" style="color:#868686;">&times;</span>
        <span class="sr-only">Close</span>
    </button>
    <!--<h3 class="modal-title">Acquire Documents</h3>-->
</div>
<iframe id="vault" ng-src="{{iframeUrl}}" style="z-index: 1000; -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch  !important; width: 100%; overflow: scroll; height: 700px;  padding-right: 15px" target="_parent" scrolling="yes" frameBorder="0" ></iframe>
<shoebox-loader backdrop="true" loading="showLoading"></shoebox-loader>
```

I tried what is suggested in [iFrame scrolling not working on iOS devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45212227/iframe-scrolling-not-working-on-ios-devices) but that didn't help.

I also tried setting the `position: absolute` for the iframe but that didn't help either.

Can someone help me with whats going wrong?